# Killing jobs submitting from an exited bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I wrote a bash script that submits a bunch of background jobs and then exits. I realized that I ran with the wrong input and they'll run for way too long. Is there a way for me to kill these jobs from the terminal since the script has exited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the output of `ps -ef`.
If you can identify the processes, you can `kill` the specific PIDs.